# How do I write a unique constraint as a trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am creating a new table in an Oracle database, and I am trying to learn how to create triggers.  To start, I figured I would try to create a basic trigger that checks for existing values prior to insert or update.  Down the road, this will be handled as a constraint, but I'm also going to need some triggers that compare values between other existing rows and columns, so I would like to know how I would write this as a trigger.

What I am trying to achieve:  Create a trigger that only allows a row to be created if no other rows in the table contain the identical TEMPLATE_ID and PRE_TEMPLATE_ID values that are attempting to be entered in the new row.

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_redundancy
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON SCHEMA.TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.TEMPLATE_ID NOT IN
        (SELECT
            A.TEMPLATE_ID
        FROM
            SCHEMA.TABLE A
        WHERE
            NEW.PRE_TEMPLATE_ID = A.PRE_TEMPLATE_ID)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE (ID, TEMPLATE_ID, PRE_TEMPLATE_ID, DATE_CREATED, CREATED_BY)
        VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.TEMPLATE_ID, NEW.PRE_TEMPLATE_ID, NEW.DATE_CREATED, NEW.CREATED_BY);
    END IF;
END;
```

When I run this, I receive the following errors:

"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"
"ORA-06512: at line 14"

(worth noting - it always is telling me that error at line 14... even if i remove everything between the BEGIN and END, it still says that error at line 14).

So I assume there is a variable (or variables) that I am supposed to be declaring somewhere, but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Comment: The line number in the PL/SQL error is counted from the BEGIN, not the CREATE TRIGGER. Your PL/SQL block doesn't have 14 lines though. Is this really what you're running? You aren't prefixing `:NEW` with a colon, you should not re-insert the row inside the trigger (which would just cause the trigger to fire again until Oracle killed it), and you will get a mutating table error if you try to select from the same table the trigger is against. Oracle [recommends](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHCEBAE) you don't use triggers for constraints unless you have to.

Comment: Triggers are a fundamentally problematic approach to validating relationships between data in different rows of the same table.  You can make it work with 3 triggers and a collection in a package (or a compound trigger) but that's generally a hideously complicated way to approach that problem.  Generally, needing to validate relationships between rows implies that you have a data model problem that should be addressed.

Comment: @AlexPoole - actually, I get the following errors - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 14.  The weird thing is, even if I delete everything between the BEGIN and END, it still returns the same error at line 14.  (updated OP with both errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `before insert` trigger fires **before** the insert, not instead of it.  The insert will happen naturally after this trigger, provided no exception has been raised. If using such a trigger for validation the code should be more like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_redundancy
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON SCHEMA.TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.TEMPLATE_ID IN
        (SELECT
            A.TEMPLATE_ID
        FROM
            SCHEMA.TABLE A
        WHERE
            NEW.PRE_TEMPLATE_ID = A.PRE_TEMPLATE_ID)
    THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Your error message here');
    END IF;
END;
```

As @Alex has said in his comment, this really isn't a good idea anyway - constraints are much more reliable and safe.  With a trigger like this it is very easy to end up with duplicates when users in 2 different sessions insert the same data at roughly the same time.  And you will also have issues with "the table is mutating".

Comment: Not to mention the mutating table errors that a before trigger will raise for querying the table that the trigger resides on....and I see that you just added that to your answer lol